# Failed to send notification.: Internal server error. No devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting the error below when sending push notification to android devices

```
 { code: 'FPWSE0009E',
      message: 'Internal server error. No devices found.',
      productVersion: '8.0.0.00-20161122-1902' 
}
```

I have done the following verification:

1: Verify that the device show up in the MFP console

2: Verify that the device is register by executing the rest call ->https://myservre/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/devices and

3: The below activity is in the manifest file

```
 <activity android:name="com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushNotificationHandler" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

4: Added the scope 'push.mobileclient'

This issue only happens for Android devices . I can send push notification to iOS phones..

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using android 5.1.1 or android 6.0?

Comment: SM-G930T android 6.0.1 and 
Nexus 7 android 5.1

Comment: have u found any solution on this?

Comment: Sorry No.. I have move away for MFP and started using Flutter

Answer (score 0):

I do not see listed a step saying that you visited the FCM console, copied from there the project identifier and senderId values and added those in the MobileFirst Console.

This step is part of the instructions, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#google-cloud-messaging--firebase-cloud-messaging

Once you do that, delete the app from the device and reinstall it.
If it fails still then also add the full LogCat log from when you open the device until after you get the error in the console.